# Neuraxle Select Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neuraxle

Whats the NeurAxle way to select a subset of columns from a dataset? This is how i am doing it via sklearn:

```
class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.columns]



# Set up SIMPLE FEATURES
simple_cols = ['BEDCERT', 'RESTOT', 'INHOSP', 'CCRC_FACIL',
               'SFF', 'CHOW_LAST_12MOS', 'SPRINKLER_STATUS',
               'EXP_TOTAL', 'ADJ_TOTAL']
    
simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
    ('impute', SimpleImputer())
])
```

EDIT:-

I think this is one solution but im not 100% convinced.

```
class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseTransformer, ForceHandleMixin):

    def __init__(self, required_columns):
        BaseTransformer.__init__(self)
        ForceHandleMixin.__init__(self)
        self.required_columns = required_columns

    def inverse_transform(self, processed_outputs):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.required_columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: this was fixed. See usage example of the column transformer here:
https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/examples/sklearn/plot_cyclical_feature_engineering.html#sphx-glr-examples-sklearn-plot-cyclical-feature-engineering-py

---

There is already an issue for this: https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/issues/168

I would be tempted to not use Pandas for now, and instead use the provided ColumnTransformer: https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.steps.column_transformer.html

If you get to fully code (and properly unit test) your Pandas Transformer, we'd be glad to have your contribution by opening a pull request on Neuraxle and adding you as a contributor.

Until then, you could code a simple `PandasToNumpy` step that would return the `.values` in a call to `transform`, and then using the existing `ColumnTransformer` of Neuraxle by providing the integers of the desired columns instead of the strings.

Also note that you can inherit from the `NonFittableMixin` to override the `fit` as a return self without additional code.

Comment: Understood will give it a go. Thanks.